# Como entrar um elemento num array usando dados de outro array?

Tags: javascript

Possuo dois arrays, um que está idMarca e nomeMarca (esse que preciso imprimir dentro do arrayVeiculos que possui idMarca), trocar idMarca por seu nome

```js
listaTabela() {
    let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerText = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayVeiculos.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < this.arrayMarcas.length; j++){
            if(this.arrayMarcas[j].idMarca === this.arrayVeiculos[i].idMarca){
                //Preciso imprimir no lugar td_marca.innerText = this.arrayVeiculos[i].idMarca;
            }

        }

        let tr = tbody.insertRow();

        let td_id = tr.insertCell();
        let td_modelo = tr.insertCell();
        let td_marca = tr.insertCell();
        let td_preco = tr.insertCell();
        let td_acoes = tr.insertCell();



        td_id.innerText = this.arrayVeiculos[i].id;
        td_modelo.innerText = this.arrayVeiculos[i].nomeModelo;
        td_marca.innerText = this.arrayVeiculos[i].idMarca; //Preciso imprimir nomeMarca de outro array aqui sem tirar o id da Respectiva marca
        td_preco.innerText = this.arrayVeiculos[i].preco;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa buscar a marca pelo id dela a cada iteração.

Isso pode ser feito usando o método `find()`, mas se preferir pode também continuar usando este *loop* já existente no código. Veja detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Exemplo de uso do método `find()`.

```js
const veiculos = [{
  modelo: 'Modelo 1',
  idMarca: 1
},
{
  modelo: 'Modelo 1.1',
  idMarca: 1
},
{
  modelo: 'Modelo 2',
  idMarca: 2
}];

const marcas = [{
  idMarca: 1,
  nome: 'Marca 1'
},
{
  idMarca: 2,
  nome: 'Marca 2'
}];

for (let veiculo of veiculos)
{
  let marca = marcas.find(m => m.idMarca == veiculo.idMarca);
  console.log(`Modelo: ${veiculo.modelo}`);
  console.log(`Id marca: ${veiculo.idMarca}`);
  console.log(`Marca ${marca.nome}`);
  console.log('\n');
}
```